# Does anybody here know how a pH probe's glass bulb electrode works?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

The glass bulb electrode is an order one century old tool. I thought [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/72222/16035) would have been answered quickly. Instead even with a little bit of an imitation of a [bounty dance](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3030/16035), zero nibbles.

Is there anything I can do to improve its chances of this getting some kind of an answer? What might the problems be with the question such that it might be off-putting to those that have some knowledge?

Am I looking for an answer that's too vague or imprecise? I'd even take a good reference in lieu of a detailed answer. So far when I pull books of library shelves they seem to tiptoe around these details. Maybe I don't know the right books?

All suggestions welcome!

Comment: I think there is not much to do. You certainly did your homework, I mean research, and the question itself is well received. It may just be that no-one (here) has the time or knowledge to answer it. Sometimes it just takes more time. Don't give up just yet.

Comment: It's actually a really complex question. When there's a pH difference across a glass membrane, it develops a measurable and repeatable potential difference. *Why* that potential develops.... if the answer is in the literature, it's in *very old* literature, and it's a phenomenon that's been "known" for so long that few people alive likely even know the full explanation. I agree with @Martin-マーチン, give it time -- the answer will probably be forthcoming eventually.

Comment: "Durable" is a questionable term, I would argue. pH probes are ultimately consumables, just with fairly long lifetimes in most circumstances. As well - "host of other measurements"? Such as? In most other glass-bulb probes I know of, the bulb is highly porous, and is basically serving as a hollow frit.

Comment: Are you sure? There's a whole raft of ion-selective electrodes that use a lot more than just a glass bulb. Why would people have made these if a pH electrode would have worked for the purpose? I'm interested to read more about them if they do exist, though.

Comment: @hBy2Py OK this is interesting. I'm going to clean up some of these comments (this is not meta related), do some further reading, then ask a question about this. I'll let you know when I post it. Thanks!

Comment: @hBy2Py OK thanks for the encouragement. Once I started reading about the glass bulb electrode I just became really intrigued by it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per @Martin-マーチン's [comment](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3707/#comment5540_3707):

> Sometimes it just takes more time. Don't give up just yet.

Indeed, a cyclohexane molecule has just posted [a very helpful answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/80948/16035) and discussion of the glass membrane. OK *it wasn't an actual molecule* that wrote the post, but the user @a-cyclohexane-molecule.

The answer was definitely worth the wait! `+n!`

Comment: Well, I'm glad that worked out :D