# Ask questions about [pericyclic] and [group-theory]!

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

The proposal [here](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3813/encouraging-better-questions-the-topic-challenge) seemed to go down well, and in the spirit of 'just trying this and seeing if it works', here we go with Topic Challenge I.

---

Let's start the Chemistry Topic Challenge with [pericyclic](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pericyclic) and [group-theory](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/group-theory).

I've picked these as they're generally broad topics which are under-represented here on chem.SE at present. In future (if this works...) it would be good if the community could decide what the challenge tags were, possibly by answering on the initial proposal with suggestions (and an explanation and rationale for *why* you want that tag).

In terms of what questions you can ask, anything goes as long as it's on-topic and broadly related to one of the chosen tags. Feel free to ask one/several  questions on either/both, but remember that this is about encouraging quality questions, so lets not just add to the 'close' queue!

For any questions I think need or deserve it, I'll add (or try and coordinate) some bounties and in two weeks time I'll post an answer here with the stats on how many questions have been asked on these tags, how many answers those questions have had and anything else notable.

Remember to tag the question with the relevant tag (there is no specific topic challenge tag, and theres no need to try and make one).

If you have any questions, you can ask them here or bring it up in chat.

(Largely copied from GraphicDesign.SE with some modifications/additions).

Comment: As a side note, is there a specific end date? We sort of agreed on two weeks, did we...? (i.e. Jul 19)

Comment: @orthocresol, I think two weeks is sensible. Im not sure a week is long enough for people to 1. realise whats going on, and 2. think up something to ask

Comment: Yup, agreed. $ $

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## The results of Topic Challenge 1

The first topic challenge was  moderately successful, though its difficult to really judge after a single attempt (one issue I can see with this whole idea is that it will be *incredibly* dependant upon the nature of the [tags](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tags) chosen. Given that doing this requires very little effort (other than a mod featuring the post), and hasn't (yet) caused any issues (poor quality questions etc.), I propose we try it for a few more weeks with new tags and see what happens.

Overall,  handful of new, questions was asked  (see below), and several older questions relating to these topics were dug up (with bounties applied). Although the challenge didn't generate quite as many new questions as hoped (especially in [pericyclic](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pericyclic)), those questions that were asked were of a high quality, and were well received.

#### Questions asked during the fortnight of the challenge:

- Three new questions were posted about [group-theory](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/group-theory), all of which received more than 10 up-votes and two of which received multiple answers

  - [Group theoretical condition for an integral to be zero](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/78760/group-theoretical-condition-for-an-integral-to-be-zero)
  - [Using group theory to make molecular orbital diagrams](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/77450/using-group-theory-to-make-molecular-orbital-diagrams)
  - [Why do we need the identity operator, E?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/77332/why-do-we-need-the-identity-operator-e)
- One new question was posted about [pericyclic](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pericyclic)

  - [Can the Smirnov-Zamkow reaction be described as a pericyclic process?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/78913/can-the-smirnov-zamkow-reaction-be-described-as-a-pericyclic-process)

#### Notable new answers to old questions

- [Theoretical basis behind orbital correlation diagram for pericyclic reactions](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/74105/theoretical-basis-behind-orbital-correlation-diagram-for-pericyclic-reactions/78998?s=1%7C0.0000#78998)
- [How do I determine the molecular vibrations of linear molecules?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/70858/how-do-i-determine-the-molecular-vibrations-of-linear-molecules/78617?s=3%7C0.0000#78617)